# swift inconsistent generic protocol restriction

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, restriction

I seem to be running into what appears to be a compiler inconsistency when passing arguments to a generic function that has a protocol restriction. I can pass a concrete argument, but not an argument as a protocol type

```
protocol Selectable {
    func select()
}

protocol Log : Selectable {
    func write()
}

class DefaultLog : Log {
    func select() {
        print("selecting")
    }
    func write() {
        print("writing")
    }
}

let concrete = DefaultLog()
let proto: Log = DefaultLog()

func myfunc<T: Selectable>(arg: T) {
    arg.select()
}

myfunc(concrete)   // <-- This works
myfunc(proto)      // <-- This causes a compiler error
proto.write()      // <-- This works fine
```

The compiler reports:

```
error: cannot invoke 'myfunc' with an argument list of type '(Log)'
myfunc(proto)
^
note: expected an argument list of type '(T)'
myfunc(proto)
^
```

If I restrict the function to the Selectable or Log protocol it still fails.

Is this a compiler bug? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a protocol, it doesn't need to be generic:

```
func myfunc(arg: Selectable) {
    arg.select()
}
```

I believe that `T` needs to be a concrete type for generics.

Comment: Ah very true, and that got me around the problem. Yes, as far as I can tell with other examples, generic types need to be concrete. Thanks!